# Is there a differentiable map surjective from low to high dimension？

Tags: gn.general-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Does there exist a map $f:\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$, where $n<m$ and $ n,m \in\Bbb N^+$ such that $f$ is surjective and differentiable?

Comment: This is impossible when $f$ is smooth, because the set of critical values of $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ will be the entire range of $f$, which has measure zero by Sard's theorem. There is a form of Sard's theorem which applies to $C^r$ functions, $r < \infty$, but the minimal $r$ to which it applies depends on $n$ and $m$.

Comment: The argument at the following link appears to generalize to any $C^1$ $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ where $n < m$, showing that this is impossible when the derivative is continuous. This is more or less the proof of Sard's theorem I know. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905299/show-that-doesnt-exist-a-continuous-differentiable-surjective-function-gamma

Comment: sard's theorem requires the derived function of f is continuous.peano cuves and hilbert cuves only need f is continuous, before  giving a strict solution,please do not underestimate the difficulty of the problem and review the questions carefully.

Comment: Sard actually called his paper  "The measure of the critical values of differentiable maps", but he really does require continuous differentiability, so I can't find a reference for differentiable but not continuously differentiable functions.

Comment: @WlodAA: as I say in my previous comment, I don't know a reference to prove such a result, and I don't see how to prove it. Would you mind giving an outline proof in an answer?

Comment: If the question was really about differentiable functions with discontinuous derivatives, maybe it could state it more clearly ? And mention that the answer is well-known in $\mathcal C^1$ regularity (cf &YCor's answer)?

Comment: This is Lemma 7.25 from Rudin's "Real and complex analysis" that the measure of the image is zero.

Comment: I'm confused by your edit, which maintains a confusing assertion: if $f$ is differentiable, then the given limsup is finite at every point.

Comment: @YCor I'm sorry that my English is so poor.It is just a assumption,not a assertion.

Comment: So sorry for my poor Englilsh level. And i just learned how to @ someone, so I never responded to the comments before. I've been a little busy lately, so I'll take time to review the answers and comments when i am not so busy.  Again, I'm sorry for my rude behavior.

Comment: I don't see any rude behavior. But you're asking about the existence of a surjective differentiable map $f$, then say that the case $f$ satisfies the limsup condition follows from measure theory, and then say that "the above condition may be not meet". I have no idea what you mean by this, since precisely the differentiable case is covered by this limsup condition. It will be useful if you edit so as to clarify. For the moment, your question is completely answered in comments and answers.

Comment: @YCor I want to explain that if $f$ satisfies the limsup condition ,we can use measure theory to proove it must not be a surjective,but it may not be met, so the problem can't be solve by this.

Comment: @weaksolution yes it does: if $f$ is differentiable, then it satisfies the limsup condition: the limsup at $x$ is actually equal to the operator norm of the differential at $x$.

Comment: @YCor I'm wrong. Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\R{\mathbf{R}}$It's easy to check that the image of any locally Lipschitz map $f:\R^n\to\R^m$ has measure zero when $n<m$ (this encompasses the case of class-$\text{C}^1$ maps, but not the case of differentiable maps).

Indeed, extend $f$ to $F:\R^m\to\R^m$ by $F(x,y)=f(x)$. This is still locally Lipschitz. So it maps the subset $\R^n$ of measure zero to a subset of measure zero, see this [MathSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139883/why-does-a-lipschitz-function-f-mathbbrd-to-mathbbrd-map-measure-zero-s) (it assumes Lipschitz, but the argument is local and $\R^m$ is a countable union of subsets on which $F$ is Lipschitz).

---

Taking into accounts the comments: here is a setting encompassing both the cases when $f$ is locally Lipschitz, and when $f$ is differentiable.

Suppose that for every $x\in\mathbf{R}^n$, we have
$$(*)\qquad F_f(x)=\limsup_{y\to x,\;y\neq x}\frac{\|f(y)-f(x)\|}{\|y-x\|}<\infty.$$

Define, for $p$ positive integer
$$X_p=\{x\in\mathbf{R}^n:\forall y\in\mathbf{R}^n:\|y-x\|\le 1/p \Rightarrow \|f(y)-f(x)\|\le p\|y-x\|\}.$$
Then $\mathbf{R}^n$ is the (countable) union of all $X_p$, and $X_p$ is a countable union of subsets $X_{p,i}$ of diameter $\le 1/p$. And $f$ is $p$-Lipschitz on $X_{p,i}$ (and also on its closure, in case one wishes to get closed subsets).

So the result indeed follows, not of the Lipschitz case as strictly said, but of the same statement replacing $\mathbf{R}^n$ with a subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$ with the restriction of the Euclidean distance (namely: for $n<m$ and $Y$ subset of $\mathbf{R}^n$, every Lipschitz function $Y\to\mathbf{R}^m$ has image of measure zero). The argument for the latter seems unchanged.

PS: for a reference, it is mentioned by @Kosh that Lemma 7.25 in Rudin's *Real and complex analysis* (initially published in 1966) does all the job: it asserts that any map $f:\mathbf{R}^m\to\mathbf{R}$ satisfying $(*)$ maps measure zero subsets to measure zero subsets. The proof given here actually seems to roughly be the same as the one written (concisely) in Rudin's book.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek wouldn't this rather fit a measure theory course? or else which analytic arguments do you have in mind?

Comment: No, the proof I know is the same. The text develops Riemann integration on compact intervals, and eventually on $\mathbb R^n$, and does a bit of baby measure theory along the way. This problem illustrates a key idea in multivariable integration, which is why I liked assigning it.

Comment: But just differentiable does not imply Lipschitz, not even locally...

Comment: @PietroMajer You're right, I've added it to emphasize.

Comment: However the set of points where F is differentiable is a countable union of sets on each of which F is Lipschitz , and by applying Lipschitz extension to each of the restrictions you are done.

Comment: @MohanRamachandran can you give me a reference for this result? You are claiming that the function the OP is looking for cannot exists. Right?

Comment: Yes. You can find the proof of a stronger result in Piotr Hajlasz lecture notes titled Geometric Analysis Lemma 2.8  page 18

Comment: So in order to let your observation and Majer remark coexisting, the result is that if a function is differentiable everywhere then it is not necessarily the case that it is locally Lipschitz but still there exist countable many measurable subsets where it's restriction is Lipschitz. So a kind of local Lipschitzianity on certain measurable subsets rather than compact subsets. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. For approximately differentiable points this is due to Federer Surface Area II TAMS 1944 vol 55 page 453 Theorem 5.2 .

Comment: @MohanRamachandran thanks. The last thing I don't get, maybe you do, is why the OP says, when talking about limsup, "unfortunately the above conditions are not necessarily met" (when a function is differentiable everywhere, I understand). At every $x$ where the function is differentiable that limsup is finite. Indeed, the argument of that limsup is bounded by the norm of the differential at $x$ plus some $\epsilon$, in a neighborhood of $x$ that depends on $\epsilon$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kosh this is a comment to the question, not to this specific answer. But indeed this limsup is finite at every point, for differentiable $f$, so this OP's claim is confusing. Maybe they mean this limsup is not necessarily (locally) bounded as function of $x$.

Comment: Well was a preamble to this one that is related to your answer. Because then the result follows immediately by Lemma 7.25 of Rudin in Real and Complex Analysis's. Just define the new function on all of R^m as you do, which will still be differentiable everywhere, and then invoke the result of Rudin as someone else also suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 34):

I don't think that the question is "at undergraduate level", and I don't understand the downvotes. That such a map does not exist for $n=1$ is a result of Morayne, *On differentiability of Peano type functions* I, II.
Colloq. Math. 53 (1987), no. 1, 129-135.

Comment: (I don't downvote anything).

Answer (score 10):

I think the image of a differentiable map $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ with $n<m$ always has measure $0$. As mentioned my @YCor in another answer, this follows from the local Lipschitz property of $f$ when $f$ is $\mathcal C^1$. Let us try to remove this hypothesis.

First, covering $\mathbb R^n$ by countably many compact sets, we reduce to proving that $f(K)$ has measure $0$ for any compact set $K$.

Fix $\epsilon >0$. For every $x \in K$, Since $f$ is differentiable at $x$, $f(B(x,r))$ is contained in a $o(r_x)$-neighbourhood of a euclidean $n$-dimensional disc of radius $\Vert \mathrm d_x f\Vert r_x$, and thus has measure
$$\Vert \mathrm d_x f\Vert^n r_x^n o(r_x^{m-n})~.$$
We can thus choose $r_x$ sufficiently small so that $f(B(x,r_x))$ has Lebesgue measure at most $\epsilon r_x^n$.

Now, the balls $B(x,\frac{1}{3}r_x)$, $x\in K$ obviously cover $K$ and we can extract a finite cover from it. Then by Vitali's lemma, we can find $x_1,\ldots, x_k$ such that the balls $B(x_i, \frac{1}{3}r_{x_i})$ are disjoint and the balls of radius $r_{x_i}$ cover $K$.

By disjointness of the balls $B(x_i,\frac{1}{3}r_{x_i})$, we get that
$$\sum_i r_{x_i}^n \leq \mathrm{Constant}\cdot \mathrm{Leb}(K)~.$$
Since the balls $B(x_i, r_{x_i})$ cover $K$ we get that
$$\mathrm{Leb}(f(K)) \leq \sum_i \mathrm{Leb}(f(B(x_i,r_{x_i})) \leq \epsilon \sum_i r_{x_i}^n~.$$
Taking $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small, we conclude that $f(K)$ has measure $0$.

**Remark:** the only regularity we need is that for every $x$, the image of $f(B(x,r))$ has volume $o(r^n)$ when $r$ goes to $0$ (with $o(r^n)$ possibly depending on the point $x$). This is satisfied for instance if $f$ is $(\frac{n}{m}+ \epsilon)$-Hölder for any $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3554381/1543

Comment: thanks for your help.